# How can I retrieve Bundle given its symbolic name?

Tags: java, osgi

Documentation for `BundleContext` says it lets you

- Get the list of bundles installed in the Framework.
- Get the Bundle object for a bundle.

However, there is no `getBundle(String symbolicName)` method, only `getBundle(long id)` (and the unsuitable `getBundle(String location)`. Of course, it's possible to call `getBundles()` and iterate over the returned array, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think iterating through the array of `getBundles()` is fine. Maybe it shouldn't exist at all because the symbolic name does not identify uniquely a bundle. Maybe `getBundles(String symbolicName)`...

From OSGi Service Platform Core Specification, Release 4, Version 4.3:

> 3.6.2 Bundle-SymbolicName
>
> The `Bundle-SymbolicName` manifest header is a mandatory header. The
>   bundle symbolic name and bundle version identify a unique bundle. This
>   does not always imply that this pair is unique in a framework, in
>   certain cases the same bundle can be installed multiple times in the
>   same framework, see Bundle Identifiers on page 89.

The referred page 89 (which actually is page 95):

> 4.4.1 Bundle Identifiers
>
> [...]
>
> Though the pair is unique, it is possible to install the same bundle
>   multiple times if the `org.osgi.framework.bsnversion` framework
>   launching property is set to multiple.

Comment: "in certain cases the same bundle can be installed multiple times in the same framework" Good point, I didn't think of that.

Comment: In this sentence I think the spec speaks about installing a jar with the same symbolic name *and* the same version number multiple times. (Not installing bundles with the same symbolic name but different version numbers.) It worth checking the referred chapter 4.4.1.

Comment: To clarify... before OSGi R4.3, the pair of `Bundle-SymbolicName` (BSN) and Bundle-Version **was** always unique. In 4.3 the `ResolverHook` API was added, which allows us to customise and filter the way in which bundles are resolved, for example to build composite applications with subsystems. In this scenario it may be possible that two bundles with the same BSN and version could be installed, for example in two different "regions". But this is an advanced use-case.

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen an example on how to do that. But there is the `PackageAdmin` service, maybe you want to have a look at this, but it seems to be deprecated. The replacement package `org.osgi.framework.wiring` does not seem to provide such a method.

And to clarify: What is your purpose of having an instance of a Bundle?